# islower() function not working in C++. What should I do?

Tags: c++, string, function

I was writing a code and could not get my mistake. Finally, when I did, I was surprised.
`islower()` is not working or maybe I am stressed out of doing coding for the past 2 hours. Will anyone help me out here? But the function `isupper()` is working fine. I am using VS Code.

This is the code I wrote to test the `islower()` function:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char c;
    cin>>c;
    if(islower(c)==true)
    cout<<"Lower";
    else
    cout<<"Upper";
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
c
Upper
```

For `isupper()`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char c;
    cin>>c;
    if(isupper(c)==true)
    cout<<"Upper";
    else
    cout<<"Lower";
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
C
Upper
```

Comment: Try without the `==true`. It's superfluous anyway. Might be causing the error.

Comment: `islower` returns an integer value. Were it to return 2 it wouldn't equal to `true` yet would indicate that it is a lower case

Comment: And that, boys and girls, is why you don't sprinkle your code with boolean literals - or any literals.

Comment: Turning on warnings and warnings as errors would have immediately found the problem: `warning C4805: '==': unsafe mix of type 'int' and type 'bool' in operation`

Comment: Do try and pay attention to indentation here. You're not doing it consistently and your code will end up very confused in a hurry if you don't make an effort to maintain that. If you're ever stuck on a problem, try cleaning up your code, just organizing it better, as often that allows you to see the issue more clearly.

Comment: `if (something==true)` is generally more simply written as `if (something)`. In this case it's the difference between working and non-working code.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the precise definitions of these functions. `isupper()` and `islower()` return `int`, and you are comparing an `int` with a `bool` constant. The `bool` when compared to an `int`, by integer promotion rules becomes an `int` with the value 1 (`true`) or 0 (`false`).

Add this to your program to see what is happening:

```cpp
    cout << "low " << islower(c) << endl;
    cout << "up " << isupper(c) << endl;
```

You will find that these functions when returning "truth" are returning a value that is not 1.

Your program will work properly when written along the lines of:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  char c;
  cin>>c;
  if (isupper(c)) {
    cout<<"Upper";
  } else {
    cout<<"Lower";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This works because `if` considers any nonzero value as "truth". You may find references in to "truthy" values and "truthiness" as a way to describe this concept.

Answer (score -1):

In cppreference, the behavior of the std::islower and std::isupper functions is undefined if the passed char value. As indicated, it should be converted to an unsigned char for safety.

Anyway, your problem comes from the fact that the std::islower and std::isupper functions return an integer value, so you should not compare it as a boolean value (true, false). Then, you should compare the result with the integer value 0.

Comment: > _behavior of the functions is undefined if the passed value is of type char_. No, it is undefined is passed value is not representable as unsigned char, which is not the case there.

Comment: Good point. Not 100% accurate though. It's UB if it's not *representable* as `unsigned char`. For ASCII (like "c" in the example), that's the case.

Comment: Both `char` and `unsigned char` use one byte (that's 8 bits) as storage. The difference is whether the first of these is interpreted as sign or a number. ASCII (like "c") takes up the lowest 7 bits and leaves the problematic bit out. So ASCII cannot cause UB. As you don't know what the user is going to enter, you should definitely sanitize your input. It's not the problem, here.